token CSRF laravel 11
Tengo un problema quiero envar un conjunto de datos de mi front en vue a mi back en laravel 11 pero me regresa la solicitud ya agregue la ruta a validateCsrfTokens pero me sigue marcando el mismo error.
mi back por el momento lo saco por el puerto 8001 .
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
    api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
    commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
)
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    //
    $middleware->alias([
        'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
        'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware::class,
        'role_or_permission' => 
 \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
    ]);
    $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
        'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/addCollaborator',
    ]);
  })
  ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    //
  })->create();

// es ta mi ruta
Route::middleware(['api'])->group(function () {
   Route::post('/addCollaborator', [CollaboratorsController::class, 'store']);
});

// y esto me regresa

